# Is sqlite INSERT..ON CONFLICT..DO UPDATE supported in Swift 4.1?

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift4.1, sqlite.swift

I've been unsuccessfully trying to implement the following:

```
var queryResult: OpaquePointer? 
var query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id, remarks, status) VALUES (?,?,?) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET remarks=?, status=?"            

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbase, query, -1, &queryResult, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    sqlite3_bind_int(queryResult, 1, 7)                      // insert id
    sqlite3_bind_text(queryResult, 2, "my remarks, -1, nil)  // insert remarks      
    sqlite3_bind_int(queryResult, 3, 1)                      // insert status 
    sqlite3_bind_text(queryResult, 4, "my remarks, -1, nil)  // update remarks      
    sqlite3_bind_int(queryResult, 5, 1)                      // update status 
}
```

But I keep getting this error on *sqlite3_prepare_v2*:

```
sqlite3 error (near "ON": syntax error)
```

Is there some issue with my execution or does Swift 4.1 **sqlite3** simply not support **ON CONFLICT**?

TIA

Comment: That's sqlite code not swift???  What version of sqlite are you using?

Comment: Wouldn't that be dependent on the device?

Comment: That UPSERT syntax requires sqlite 3.24 or newer. The version of Swift doesn't matter (unless it comes with a particular fixed version of sqlite instead of using some system-wide shared library version)

Comment: Just checked with **sqlite3_libversion()**. It's v.3.16. Thank you, Shawn.